# If the $m \times n$ linear system $Ax = b$ has a unique solution then $r = n$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

Statement $S$:

If an $m \times n$ (consistent) linear system $Ax = b$ has a unique solution then $r = n$. $r$ is the number of nonzero rows in the row reduced echelon form (RREF) of $A$.

How to prove this statement $S$?

Is the word *consistent* necessary in $S$?

I have another related theorem here:

Theorem $T$: Let $[C | d]$ be an $[m×(n+1)]$ matrix in reduced echelon form, where $[C | d]$ represents a consistent system. Let $[C | d]$ have $r$ nonzero rows. Then $r \le n$ and in the solution of the system there are $n − r$ variables that can be assigned arbitrary values.

and its corollary:

By Theorem $T$, the only possibilities for the system represented by $[C | d]$ (and hence for the system represented by $[A | b]$) are:

1. The system is inconsistent.
2. The system is consistent and, in the notation of statement $S$, $r < n$. In this
   case there are $n − r$ unconstrained variables, so the system has infinitely many
   solutions.
3. The system is consistent and $r = n$. In this case there are no unconstrained
   variables, so the system has a unique solution.

Don't know how to use theorem $T$.

Answer (score 1):

> $$Ax=b$$

Theorem $T$ means: If there exists some solution $x$, it means $b\in\text{col}A$. Further, if this solution is unique, it means $\ker A=\{0\}$. Next, by Rank Theorem,

$$n=\dim \text{col}A+\dim\ker A=r+0=r $$

So the proof is complete. Note the dimension of the column space of $A$ equals the number of nonzero rows in the row reduced echelon form (RREF) of $A$.

Comment: Is it possible to answer the question with Theorem $T$ and its corollary. Without using kernel and rank nullity theorem.

Comment: They are the same thing, just give a different name. $\dim\ker A=$ "how many free variable in your RREF". If it is unique solution, then "number of free variables $= 0$", so $\dim\ker A=0$